# List values accidentally replaced inside function

Tags: python, list, assign

I have a List of List (tableData) and I want to return a new List (cloneTable) that outputs the length of each string in the original List so I can find the longest string using the function longestString. I also want to keep the values in the original List. The problem is that after my function runs, the original List has been converted to lengths.

I am sure the code can be better (I am still learning) but I also want to understand WHY there is this problem. I did not Assign tableData I am passing the values from tableData to assign to cloneTable. Thanks for the help!

```
#A list of lists
tableData = [
    ['apples','oranges','cherries','banana'], #6,7,8,6
    ['Alice','Bob','Carol','David'], #5,3,5,5
    ['dogs','cats','moose','goose'], #4,4,5,5
    ['car','train','helicopter','plane'] #3,5,10,5
]

#longestString function finds the longest string in each list of list
def longestString(table):
    cloneTable = []
    output = []

    for v1 in range(len(table)):
        cloneTable = cloneTable + [table[v1]]

    for v1 in range(len(cloneTable)):
        for v2 in range(len(cloneTable)):
            cloneTable[v1][v2] = len(cloneTable[v1][v2])

        cloneTable[v1].sort()

    for v1 in range(len(cloneTable)):
        output = output + [cloneTable[v1][-1]]

    return output

##################################################################

for v1 in range(len(tableData)): #returns the list - OK
    print(tableData[v1])

print(longestString(tableData)) #returns the longest strings - OK

for v1 in range(len(tableData)): #returns a list of string lengths - Not OK
    print(tableData[v1])
```

Comment: A more advanced solution might be something like `[max(l, key=len) for l in tableData]` This takes advantage of the [max](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) function and a concept called [list comprehension](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you call your list `cloneTable` if it is just a reference copy/assignment you're doing.

You should perform a deep copy of your list if you really want to clone it. A cross-python solution involves using `copy.deepcopy`:

```
import copy
def longestString(table):
    cloneTable = []
    output = []

    cloneTable = copy.deepcopy(table)
    ...
```

Comment: @Soviut Incorrect, we're dealing with a nested list.

Comment: Ah you're right, I missed that due to the indentation. I'm going to clarify that in the question.